# Ubuntu Server Error

Tags: server

I'M seeing the following error occur at various times.
My server is private for learning, no commercial or
company involved.

The hardware is as follows:

- Memory is 16gb (max memory for the computer)
- Hard drive is 1TB

The Ubuntu server 23.10 error is:

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 actioin 0x6 frozen
ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 14
                res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status. { DRDY }
```

Has anyone experienced this error and if so is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your drive(s) could have errors. Create a back up, then try this

1. `umount /dev/sdX` the drive, or just boot to a live ubuntu USB
2. `e2fsck -pf /dev/sdX` `p` does auto repair, `f` says just check it even if clean

Next I'd look at RAM, take out one stick at a time and run memtester

```
sudo apt-get install memtester
```

Then test almost all 16GB of RAM

```
sudo memtester 14G 1
```

Look for bios updates to the motherboard and firmware updates for peripherals if drives and RAM pass testing. I suspect drives first. Let us know what you figure out and if any of these things helped.

Comment: I agree about hard disk error, [related post](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=77687).

Answer (score 0):

The 3TB SATA hard drive arrived along with new SATA cables.
I installed the 3TB hard drive and new cables then installed
Ubuntu Server 23.10. So far, over a 3 day period, I have not
seen that same error again. It appears the 1TB drive had problems
that contributed to the error.